# How to dispose a MemoryStream that is used in a Task?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following method:

```
public void Write() {
     var tasks = new List<Task>();
     while(...) {
         var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(...);
         var task = _pageBlob.WritePagesAsync(memoryStream, ... );
         tasks.Add(task);
     }    
     Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

How to correctly dispose `memoryStream` that in `Task`? I need to dispose the `memoryStream` object when the task is finished.

Comment: You don't need to dispose MemoryStream but the question is valid still. It can be good for code quality to put it into `using`.

Comment: How can I put it into a `using`? I need to do `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());` after a loop

Comment: Add `using` to the code of one of the answers. They should have used it in the first place but maybe they just didn't bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split out your `while` loop body into a separate `async` method:

```
private async Task WriteAsync(...)
{
  using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(...))
  {
    await _pageBlob.WritePagesAsync(memoryStream, ...);
  }
}
```

Then use your new method:

```
public void Write() {
  var tasks = new List<Task>();
  while(...) {
    tasks.Add(WriteAsync(...));
  }    
  Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

On a side note, blocking on asynchronous code (`Task.WaitAll`) is not generally a good idea. A more natural approach is to keep it asynchronous:

```
public async Task WriteAsync() {
  var tasks = new List<Task>();
  while(...) {
    tasks.Add(WriteAsync(...));
  }    
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the cleanest way. There is no reason to do anything else.

Comment: When we dispose a stream?

Comment: @Anatoly: The stream is disposed at the end of the `using` block.

Comment: So I will dispose a stream, and when the task is NOT finished?

Comment: @Anatoly: No, the `await` will (asynchronously) wait for the `WritePagesAsync` task to complete, and *then* the stream is disposed.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1-Encapsulate all the process inside a task:

```
while(...) {

     var task = Task.Run(async () => {

         var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(...);
         var res = await _pageBlob.WritePagesAsync(memoryStream, ... );
         memoryStream.Dispose();

     });

     tasks.Add(task);
 }
```

2-Use a Continuation:

```
 while(...) {
     var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(...);
     var task = _pageBlob.WritePagesAsync(memoryStream, ... )
                .ContinueWith((PrevTask) => memoryStream.Dispose());

     tasks.Add(task);
 }
```

Comment: Well, there are a ton more of ways of doing this (per example having an external List<Stream> where you hold the strerams and dispose them after the WaitAll), but these two ways are the ones using the Async framework.

Comment: I need to dispose the `memoryStream` object when the task is finished.
I don't want to have `async/await` keywords. How to add continuation and dispose stream inside it?

Comment: You don't need to do Task.Run inside ContinueWith, why would you run task just to dispose that stream? Just do: .ContinueWith(_ => memoryStream.Dispose());

Comment: Gosh, you're right, I'm not very used to continuations and I always used the overloads which continues with other tasks... let me update the answer

Comment: How can I add `.ContinueWith` to a `Task`, not to a `WritePagesAsync` ?

Comment: WritePagesAsync returns a task, ContinueWith is added to any task and returns a new task including the continuation. The code above is the same as *var task = _pageBlob.WritePagesAsync(...); task = task.ContinueWith(...);*

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public void Write()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    while (...)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(...);
        var task = WritePagesAsync(memoryStream, ...);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

private async Task WritePagesAsync(MemoryStream memoryStrem, ...)
{
    await _pageBlob.WritePagesAsync(memoryStrem);
    memoryStrem.Dispose();
}
```